# Python Object not callable

Tags: python, class, typeerror, callable

I'm new to python:

Created a Class:

```
class NodeStruct:
"""Struct to hold node data for search trees"""

  def __init__(self, name, children, parent_name, edge_weight):
      self.name = name
      self.childNodes = children
      self.parent = parent_name
      self.weight = edge_weight

  def name(self):
      return self.name

  def parent(self):
      return self.parent

  def path_cost(self):
      return self.weight

  def children(self):
      return self.childNodes

  def child_keys(self):
      return self.childNodes.keys()
```

Instantiate:

```
this_node = NodeStruct(start, problem[start], 'root', 0)
```

The Problem: when I make a call to name()

```
name = this_node.name()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Looks like it should be straight forward... What am I missing?

Comment: you're overwriting the method in the constructor `self.name = name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which one of the `name`s do you expect `this_node.name()` to find?

```
      self.name = name
      # ...

  def name(self):
      return self.name
```

The solution is likely to change the name of the attribute to `self._name`:

```
      self._name = name
      # ...

  def name(self):
      return self._name
```

Answer (score 4):

When you define your class, `name` is a function. As soon as you instantiate it, though, `__init__` is called, and `name` is immediately set to whatever you pass in (a string in this case). The names of functions are not kept separate from the names of other objects. Use a unique name.

Comment: You were first to answer but the code example from @ev-br did help me to understand it somewhat more but I will uptick because I understand what you are getting out.